# How to solve $vv''+v'^2-6t^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

**Hi, I have been trying to solve this equation for a week now.**

However, I keep ending up with the same result everytime, it may be because my knowledge on this chapter is not great.

I am unable to figure it out, please help.

Below is the question and the conditions.

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> vv''+v'^2-6t^2=0 \\ 
> v'(0)=0,\\
> v(0)=1,\\
> v>0\quad\forall t
> \end{cases}$$

They are asking to use the substitution $z=vv'$  to solve the equation, and 
[here you can find my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw8GK.jpg), but I am obviously unsure if it is the correct way of solving the exercise.

Thank you so much, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can notice the integral of $z = v_tv$ is $u = \int z dt =  \frac{v^2}{2}$. So using the substitution $u = v^2$. You then get $u'' -12t^2=0$. This is then solvable with the standard methods of solving differential equations.

$u'' = 12t^2 \implies u = t^4+c_1t+c_2 \implies v = \sqrt{t^4+c_1t+c_2}$

Now, we plug in initial conditions and we are done:

$v(0) = 1 = \sqrt{0^4+c_1(0)+c_2} \implies c_2 = 1$

$v'(0) = 0 = \frac{4(0)^3+c_1}{2\sqrt{(0^4+c_1(0)+1}} \implies c_1=0$

So the solution is:

$v = \sqrt{t^4+1}$

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed steps!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**
$$vv''+v'^2=6t^2$$
Rewrite it as:
$$(v'v)'=6t^2$$
$$(v^2)''=12t^2$$
And integrate.

---

With $z=vv'$ rewrite the DE as:
$$z'=6t^2$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome @deenodebt1